# Meaning of ? in Java

Tags: java, ternary-operator

```
ltVal = node.left  != null ? node.left.height  : 0;
```

I think this is written in Java, can anyone explain what this means? Can't understand this shorthand notation

Comment: Did you really tag this with "line"? I think you misunderstood the tag.

Comment: Have a read of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: If `node.left` is not `null` assign its height to `ltVal` else assign the value zero to it. Google "Ternary Operators"

Comment: @alfasin now that's readable, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called  **ternary operator** and it is only operator that takes `3` operands. In better sense, it is conditional operator that represent shorter format

**General Syntax** :

```
boolean expression ? value1 : value2
```

your example:

```
ltVal = node.left  != null ? node.left.height  : 0;
```

as same as

```
  if( node.left != null)
       itVal = node.left.height
  else
       itval = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing things, I get confused most of the times if I don't see any parenthesis xD Didn't realize it was a ternary operator being assigned to "ltVal" until someone explained xD

Comment: @ZeferiniX do not worry you will get use to it. you should get to use this kind of coding cuz lambda has already arrived in Java. :)

Comment: Is it a good practice not to put parenthesis? Most examples I find that uses ternary operators don't have parenthesis @_@ Could've understand this better if it was 

    ltVal = ( (node.left  != null) ? node.left.height  : 0 );

Comment: @ZeferiniX I think using parenthesis is up to how much experience you have in programming :)